# Sybase Select View And Table

Tags: sybase

Is it possible to select a view and table with one select statement? For example:

Table1
Col1 | Col2

View1
Col1 | Col2

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T1.COL1) FROM Table1 T1,View1 V1 WHERE V1.Col2 = T1.COL2 AND T1.COL1 = "something"
```

Comment: Hi, I see you've logged into SO recently, but have not accepted my answer.  If there were any problems with it, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a Table and a View in a Join.

Logically, a view is treated as a table, so you can do most actions that are available to tablesl, including joins.

Comment: Michael is correct; you can do what you are asking. That SQL sample in the description is an implied inner join, so the count will yield results that exist only within the table, and in the view.  I tested your syntax in dbisqlc against ASA9 and it ran without and problem and gave me the results I expected.